# Firebase Google OAuth 2.0 returns auth/network-request-failed in Angular 2 SPA

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I created a Firebase SPA app based on Angular2/TypeScript. I activated Google Auth in Firebase console, added localhost:4200 to authorized JavaScript origins in Google console (this record was created by Firebase automatically) and call the following code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

let prov = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(prov)
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    debugger;
  });
```

but I receive auth/network-request-failed every time right after. It looks like I missed to set up some settings but can't find which. A couple of months ago I did similar experiments but it didn't require anything special besides I did this time. I noticed that this could happen on Chrome but in my case, it repros on Firefox and IE either.

**UPDATE.**
I checked server response in the browser: it cancels the request with the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<project id>"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions."
 }
}
```

Then I deleted all keys that were created by Firebase and recreate them. Put both localhost and firebase host references to there - same thing.

**UPDATE**. This is not a Firebase issue but more like Angular integration: I created a simple Angular2 project, repeated same actions but without Angular services like in first place and the problem is gone. Now I try to reproduce to find what happened. Will update this post in case I find anything.

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the console for detailed errors on what is timing out? This is one of the most common errors and it is hard to debug without details.

Comment: I added error details to the question body. I think that this is more Google Identity Toolkit issue. Also, I killed both Firebase and related Google projects, recreated them from scratch and got the same error.

Comment: You have added referrer restrictions on your browser API key. That is the reason you are getting this error. You will need to remove those restrictions in the Google Console.

Comment: No - I removed all restrictions and even recreated the key - didn't help. I still have no clue what happened but it looks like this comes from Angular: I created a simple project using angular CLI again and it started to work. Will continue to investigate. Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: I started having the same error after including a router in my project. I had the signInWithPopup working fine before that. In FireFox I have this warning: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb217841”. This iframe is needed to pass back the OAuth result to the page. Still lookingo for an answer.